# Getting Column Value from another Subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a LINQ query. But I need to get value of two columns from another subquery. This is my Linq query:

```
)from t in db.PUTAWAYs
join t0 in db.ASN_ITEM on t.AWB_NO equals t0.AWB_NO
join t1 in db.ASN_MASTER on t0.AWB_NO equals t1.AWB_NO
join t2 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t2.ITEM_CODE
join t3 in db.ASN_INPUT on t0.AWB_NO equals t3.AWB_NO
where
  t3.ITEM == t2.ITEM_CODE &&
  1 == 1 &&                          
  (fromDate == "" || toDate == "" || (t0.REC_DATE.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0 && t0.REC_DATE.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0)) &&
  (AWB_NO == "" || (t0.AWB_NO == AWB_NO))
orderby
  t.AWB_NO,
  t0.REC_DATE,
  t0.STYPE,
  t2.PART_NO
select new ASNPutawayRep
{
    AWB_NO = t.AWB_NO,
    REC_DATE = t0.REC_DATE,
    STYPE = t0.STYPE,
    PART_NO = t2.PART_NO,
    //LOCATION_AD = t.LOCATION_AD,
    QNTY = t.QNTY,
    //LOCATION_SD = t.LOCATION_SD,
    REGION_ID = t.REGION_ID
}).Distinct();
```

Here in select portion of above query, instead of directly taking value of the column `t.LOCATION_AD`, I need to get it from `SELECT LOC_NAME FROM LOCATION_MASTER WHERE LOC_CODE = t.LOCATION_AD`

and instead of `t.LOCATION_SD`, I need to get value from `SELECT LOC_NAME FROM LOCATION_MASTER where LOC_CODE = t.LOCATION_SD`

How can I write this in LINQ. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you add another join?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`let`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause. It is useful to store the result of sub-expression in order to use it in subsequent clauses.

**Example:**

```
(from t in db.PUTAWAYs
 ...
 let locAd = from l in LOCATION_MASTER where LOC_CODE = t.LOCATION_SD select l.LOC_NAME
 where
 ...
 orderby
 ...
 select new ASNPutawayRep
 {
     LOCATION_AD = locAd,
 }).Distinct();
```

Also, you can directly write LINQ without using `let` clause:

```
(from t in db.PUTAWAYs
 ...
 where
 ...
 orderby
 ...
 select new ASNPutawayRep
 {
     LOCATION_AD = from l in LOCATION_MASTER where LOC_CODE = t.LOCATION_SD select l.LOC_NAME
 }).Distinct();
```

Comment: I have tried this. But getting this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'string'`

Comment: @LimnaD'silva: Updated, however, it is just an example. You're getting that error because the type of `LOC_NAME` is different from `LOCATION_AD`. Check if the type of value fetching from database is `string`, if yes, you need to check type of `LOCATION_AD` property of `ASNPutawayRep` class.

Comment: Both are declared as string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsQueryable to achieve this

```
from t in db.PUTAWAYs
join t0 in db.ASN_ITEM on t.AWB_NO equals t0.AWB_NO
join t1 in db.ASN_MASTER on t0.AWB_NO equals t1.AWB_NO
join t2 in db.ITEM_MASTER on t.ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE equals t2.ITEM_CODE
join t3 in db.ASN_INPUT on t0.AWB_NO equals t3.AWB_NO
where
  t3.ITEM == t2.ITEM_CODE &&
  1 == 1 &&                          
  (fromDate == "" || toDate == "" || (t0.REC_DATE.CompareTo(fromDate) >= 0 && t0.REC_DATE.CompareTo(toDate) <= 0)) &&
  (AWB_NO == "" || (t0.AWB_NO == AWB_NO))
orderby
  t.AWB_NO,
  t0.REC_DATE,
  t0.STYPE,
  t2.PART_NO
select new ASNPutawayRep
{
    AWB_NO = t.AWB_NO,
    REC_DATE = t0.REC_DATE,
    STYPE = t0.STYPE,
    PART_NO = t2.PART_NO,
    LOCATION_AD = (from l in db.LOCATION_MASTER 
                     where l.LOC_CODE = t.LOCATION_AD
                     select LocName)ToList().FirstorDefault(),
    QNTY = t.QNTY,
    LOCATION_SD = (from l in db.LOCATION_MASTER 
                     where l.LOC_CODE = t.LOCATION_SD
                     select LocName).ToList().FirstorDefault(),
    REGION_ID = t.REGION_ID
}).Distinct();
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got error `'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' does not contain a definition for FirstorDefault and no extension method 'FirstorDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'`

Comment: you have Sytem.Linq using statement in file where this code resides right??

Comment: Strange...It should work....I think as you are using EF whole query is passed as expression and when QueryProvider trying to execute the expression it fails...I removed AsQueryable() from answer..Pls try again

Comment: Did you try another answer given by SID?

Comment: Yeah..That also I have tried. But same error exists.

Comment: I have checked out. But it's telling `'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' does not contain a definition for FirstorDefault...`. I think it is not possible to do so in this case (to get column value using subquery):(